# Improving TeX and the picture fits perfectly in flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, user-interface, dart

I want to implement how to make a design like under image on flutter. I got this reference image:

[image]

But I don't know how to implement it, so you can improve my code on how to create a design like that in the link.

Here is my code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Image Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Image Demo'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              child: new Image.asset(
                'assets/images/1.png',
                width: 200.0,
                height: 200.0,
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Halo",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. Could you improve it?

Comment: Please see again my answer

Comment: are you still not understand my question